# Save and Load C# list of different types from JSON

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization, deserialization

I am using JSON to serialize and deserialize a list in c#. Everything works if the list is made up of objects of a single type. My goal is to find a way to store a list (or queue or something similar) of objects of different types that I can load and iterate over later and perform operations on. I could break my serialization up into multiple lists, but it is important to iterate over the objects in the order that they were added, so having them all be a part of the same data structure is ideal.

I tried having a DataModelBase class that they all inherit from and having a list of type DataModelBase, which works at runtime and when saving, but the load / deserialize function I was not able to get to work. I also tried using an interface as well and passing custom parameters to my deserialize call, but this caused my Unity application to crash. Is there a better way to go about what I am trying to achieve?

This is my load function:

```
public static T LoadData<T>(string path)
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            var fileContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(fileContents);
        }
    }
```

The error that I am commonly getting when trying to convert an entry in my list to my class type is: RuntimeBinderException: Cannot implicitly convert type `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to`Type I am trying to convert to'

Comment: If you want to keep track of what order the items were added, keep track of it in a List<Tuple<int, dynamic/object/T>>

Comment: Are these types related, e.g. do they have a base class?

Comment: Yes, they have a base class they all inherit from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) setting to save type data inside the saved JSON. This will most likely solve the deserialization issue you've seen.

From the linked documentation:

```
Stockholder stockholder = new Stockholder
{
    FullName = "Steve Stockholder",
    Businesses = new List<Business>
    {
        new Hotel
        {
            Name = "Hudson Hotel",
            Stars = 4
        }
    }
};

string jsonTypeNameAll = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stockholder, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
});

Console.WriteLine(jsonTypeNameAll);
// {
//   "$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Samples.Stockholder, Newtonsoft.Json.Tests",
//   "FullName": "Steve Stockholder",
//   "Businesses": {
//     "$type": "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Newtonsoft.Json.Samples.Business, Newtonsoft.Json.Tests]], mscorlib",
//     "$values": [
//       {
//         "$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Samples.Hotel, Newtonsoft.Json.Tests",
//         "Stars": 4,
//         "Name": "Hudson Hotel"
//       }
//     ]
//   }
// }

string jsonTypeNameAuto = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stockholder, Formatting.Indented, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
});

Console.WriteLine(jsonTypeNameAuto);
// {
//   "FullName": "Steve Stockholder",
//   "Businesses": [
//     {
//       "$type": "Newtonsoft.Json.Samples.Hotel, Newtonsoft.Json.Tests",
//       "Stars": 4,
//       "Name": "Hudson Hotel"
//     }
//   ]
// }

// for security TypeNameHandling is required when deserializing
Stockholder newStockholder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stockholder>(jsonTypeNameAuto, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
});

Console.WriteLine(newStockholder.Businesses[0].GetType().Name);
// Hotel
```

Comment: Adding type name handling solved my problems. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the json into a Dynamic. It should give you the flexibility you want but may be a bit slow

[Deserialize json object into dynamic object using Json.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net/4980689)

Alternatively you can use polymorphism

[what's the difference between inheritance and polymorphism?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325518/whats-the-difference-between-inheritance-and-polymorphism)